# Mouse event handling in Swing

Tags: java, swing, mouse, jbutton

I was wondering, how does a Swing component know where the mouse is and when it is clicked, and how could I use that in my own class, without having to add a new mouse listener every time i want to add an object to a new panel?

EDIT:
Im extending JComponent and I want to get an event method called when the mouse moves
EDIT2:
Got it working now thanks everyone!

Comment: so what exactly you want make you requirements clear. I assume you are adding an object(most probably that you have drawn using paintComponent or that would be an image) to the `JPanel` and use mouse listener on that particular object?

Comment: From a components point of view, you can't "share" the mouse listener, because most components don't actually use it themselves. You will required to make your own listener and register it against the component. That's how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an actionlistener to your JButton and it will tell you when its been clicked like so:

```
someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //the button was pressed and do your stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not using JButton, im using my own class and I want to inherit mouse listeners from the JPanel

Comment: then what prams do i give?

Comment: Whatever mouse listener you want to add :P

Answer (score 2):

`how does the JButton know where the mouse is and when it clicked`

thats what for **Listeners** are - it listens for a corresponding type of event

just implement `ActionListener` and register it to its listener by doing this:
`jbutton.addActionListener(this);`
now when you click the button it will generate an `event` which will b handled in this part

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    ... // handle event
}
```

Comment: I know that, I want to be able to receive mouse events from the JPanel, and i'm not using the JButton class, i'm writing my own class.

Comment: It'll still work if you extend JButton with your custom class (best way imo) but even if not you can make the button implement actionlistener...

Comment: *"..not using the JButton class"*  That would explain why you mentioned `JButton` in both the title and body of the question.  No wait, the other thing..  It would totally ***fail*** to explain why..

Comment: and by this ` want to add an object to a new panel?` what type of object? even if you want to implement `MouseListener` on `JPanel` - what problem you faced

Comment: Im extending JComponent and I want to get an event method called when the mouse moves

Comment: @tommy__123__ when the mouse moves?? where?? over that particular object or over the JPanel

Answer (score 0):

From the comments of the other post, you want to register a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to you custom component using [`Component#addMouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29)

You may like to have a read through [How to write a mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more info